# Entry to the United States with Advance Parole: why having to go through the immigration waiting room?

Tags: usa

When entering the United States with Advance Parole, one may have to go through the immigration waiting room. Why, and is there any way to avoid that (it often takes between 30 minutes and 60 minutes, so it's preferable not to go through it)?

Comment: Anyone, even a US citizen, may have to go to that room.

Comment: @phoog true but it looks like advance parole significantly increases the odds

Comment: @phoog a friend of mine as well as myself entered the US five times with advance parole, and 100% of the time we had to wait in the immigration room. Had never happened before when entering a dozen of times with f1 or esta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that they have to verify that the basis for the Advance Parole is still valid (e.g. for an Advance Parole based on being an Adjustment of Status applicant, they have to verify that the Adjustment of Status application hasn't been denied), and the systems needed to verify that status either isn't available, or is too slow to be used, at the primary inspection station, so they can only do it at secondary inspection.